# How do you close a tab in Dr Racket

Tags: racket

I keep accidently hitting ctrl-t in Doctor Racket, and then when it opens a new tab, the only way I know how to get rid of the unwanted new tab is by closing everything and reopening the files I want to edit.

Is there a better way?

Comment: This question is off-topic as it pertains to a specific software, not code. It should be migrated to Super User.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the tab you want to close is active, you can either select "File -> Close" in the menu or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. In the file menu you have the option called "Close" It will only close the active window so if there are more tabs only the active one will be closed.

You can do the shortcut instead, which is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> for a Windows or Linux system while its <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> on MacOS. If you see in the menu there are hints on these shortcuts.